# chrome remote desktop appears offline even when the computer has internet

Tags: chrome, remote, connection-sharing

I have two computers one with Windows 11 and another with Ubuntu 20.04. I need to access the Ubuntu computer from the Windows 11 and I need help doing it.

I installed Chrome remote desktop on the Ubuntu machine using these instructions (steps 1-6): https://www.helpwire.app/blog/chrome-remote-desktop-linux/

When I try to connect, I click on the Ubuntu machine Remote Access>Turn On> I write a name and enter a PIN. Then the computer asks me for authorization so I type my Ubuntu password. Then it happens one of the following things:

a) The remote access is not set so I have to start over from Turn On 
b) It creates the connection but it says that the Ubuntu computer is offline, which is not true because I have access to the Internet. Meanwhile, I can see from the Windows machine that the Ubuntu machine WAS online but shows the real-time (e.g., in the screenshot)
[image]

I also removed the connection and tried to set the connection multiple times but did not work. I can, however, remotely access my Windows computer from my Ubuntu computer without any problem.
I have seen that some people had this problem too but the questions are mostly addressed to Windows machines and I cannot find much information about using this tool in Linux (or Windows - Linux in my case)(https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/87740221/chrome-remote-desktop-is-showing-our-workstations-as-offline-but-they-aren-t-please-help?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Are your machines on the same network?
To obtain the local IP on Ubuntu type:

- `ifconfig`
- `sudo ifconfig` (if root privileges are required)

To obtain the public IP type: `curl ifconfig.me`

If trying to connect remotely from Windows to Ubuntu, I recommend using Window's *Remote Desktop Connection* where you would have to enter the IP address of the Ubuntu machine.
Please let me know if this works.